# Can you transpose a matrix using matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Say you have a matrix A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}

and I want it to look like $A^T$ = \begin{bmatrix}c&a\\d&b\end{bmatrix}
Can this be done via matrix multiplication? Something like a matrix T such that $T*A = A^T$.

Comment: No, you cannot !

Comment: Nope. A more interesting question is whether there is a pair $T_1, T_2$ of matrices such that $T_1 A T_2 = A^T$.

Comment: Note that your transpose is wrong.

Comment: ok thanks guys.

Comment: Of course $T$ exists if $A$ is invertible: $T = A^T A^{-1}$.  But maybe you want a fixed $T$ that works for all $A$.

Comment: That's what I said: a fixed $T$ that works for all $A$.

Comment: Ah I think I misused the word transpose. Rather rotating the matrix by 90 degrees. I'm using a matrix to represent a 2D sprite and I wonder if there was an easier way to rotate the sprite by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find it!

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
X & Y \\
Z & T 
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Hence solve the associate system system:

$$\begin{cases}
aX + bZ = a \\
aY + bT = c\\
cX + dZ = b\\
cY + dT = d
\end{cases}
$$

To find $X, Y, Z, T$.

Comment: You're multiplying the matrices in the opposite order for some reason

Answer (score 17):

If there were such a $T$, we would have that $T = T \times I = I^T = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. But then it would follow that $A = I \times A = T \times A = A^T$ for all matrices $A$; i.e., that all matrices are their own transposes. As this is not true, we conclude there cannot be any such $T$ as desired.

Comment: Excellent answer to the question as posed, although the original questioner was confused and actually meant to ask about rotating a matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Why not ? The answer is implicitly given by il maestro  @ Qiaochu Yuan. Behind this, there is a tensor; in fact, the transposition is simply a permutation. We stack the considered matrix $A$, row by row, in a column: $\bar{A}=[a,b,c,d]^T$ and $\bar{A^T}=[a,c,b,d]^T$. Thus the tensor $T$ s.t. $T\bar{A}=\bar{A^T}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Of course, we can generalize for every $n$.

We can congratulate yujinred for his ability to calculate the transpose of a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Is there a way to use this to show Det(A)=Det($A^T$)?