# Rotation of a matrix at an angle

Tags: matrices

Is there a transformation that exists which will rotate a matrix of this form
$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$ into $\begin{bmatrix}c & a\\d & b\end{bmatrix}$. I have looked into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945329/can-you-transpose-a-matrix-using-matrix-multiplication) question and I am aware that this is definitely **not** a transpose of one matrix to another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply the original matrix by $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and then take the transpose, you will get the result you want.

Answer (score 3):

Let the required matrix be $M$

Then $$M\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}c&a\\d&b\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$\implies M=\left(\begin{matrix}c&a\\d&b\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a&b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}$$
$$=\left(\begin{matrix}c&a\\d&b\end{matrix}\right)\frac{1}{ad-bc}\left(\begin{matrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\left(\begin{matrix}cd-ac&-bc+a^2\\d^2-bc&-bd+ab\end{matrix}\right)$$