# Can I create a $4\times 4$ diagonal matrix with the elements of a $2\times 2$ matrix on the diagonal through left/right matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know it's impossible to [transpose a matrix through matrix multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1945329/198724), but is it possible to convert a $2 \times 2$ matrix, e.g.

\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}

into a $4 \times 4$ matrix with $a, b, c, d$ on the diagonal, through left/right matrix multiplication?

\begin{bmatrix}a&0&0&0\\0&b&0&0\\0&0&c&0\\0&0&0&d\end{bmatrix}

In other words, are there some conformable  $L$ and $R$ such that $LAR$ equals this matrix? I initially considered these:

$$
L=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\1&0\\0&1\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
R=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

but those that doesn't work, and I haven't had any luck juggling 1s and 0s to get this to work, and I'm curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to find such $L$ and $R$ that 
$$
L 
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}
R = \begin{bmatrix}a&0&0&0\\0&b&0&0\\0&0&c&0\\0&0&0&d\end{bmatrix}$$
for all $a,b,c,d$.

If all $a,b,c,d$ are non-zero then LHS has rank at most $2$ but RHS has rank $4$.